# Correctly typing a dynamic dictionary of arrays + reduce functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class that has a list of indices that can change dynamically, as well as a dictionary of subscribed "reducers" (array + reduce function + initial value). The idea is that the reducers can be called to produce reduced values, while subsetting the array on the list of indices (I've implemented this but omitting for clarity).

I'm not sure how to type the dictionary such that the reducers can be added dynamically, so their types will be `unknown, unknown` at compile time, but each reducer must have an internally-consistent generic type:

```
type ReduceFn<T, U> = (result: U, nextValue: T, index: number) => U;
type Reducer<T, U> = { array: T[]; reducefn: ReduceFn<T, U>; initalValue: U };

class Part {
  indices: number[]
  reducers: Record<string, Reducer<unknown, unknown>>
  
  constructor(indices: number[]) {
    this.indices = indices
    this.reducers = {}
  }

  addReducer = <T, U>(key: string, reducer: Reducer<T, U>) => {
    this.reducers[key] = reducer
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the use case? (e.g., What do you intend to do with a `Part`'s `reducers` property?  Just run each property to get the output value?) The type `Reducer<T, U>` is *invariant* in both `T` and `U`, so you cannot safely assign a `Reducr<T, U>` to `Reducer<unknown, unknown>` unless `T` and `U` are both `unknown`.  If you want to just push through that you can use `Reducer<any, any>` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVYR5w). If you care a lot about type safety you'll need to refactor, and how you refactor depends on use cases not shown here. Could you [edit] to show uses?

Comment: For example, if all you can realistically do is run the reducer, you can just store something that lets you do it, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w2298w).  Does that work for you?  If not, please show the unmet use case and I can possibly modify it to handle it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, yeah the use case is to evaluate (possibly multiple) reducers, while subsetting the `array` on the `indices`. So e.g. if `indices` are `[0, 1, 2]`, and the reducers are `{sum: {array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], reducefn: (a, b) => a + b, initialValue: 0}, prod: {array: [1, 3, 5, 7], reducefn: (a, b) => a * b, 1}  }`  then the result will be: `{sum: 6, prod: 15}`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wez8EN) work for you then? (Note that `Part` will only know that the reducers return `unknown`, because `Part` isn't strongly typed enough to track the return values of individual reducers, and doing so is almost certainly out of scope for the question.) If so I'll write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?